# laravel-splade Blank page after build

Tags: laravel-10

I'm building an app with laravel 10 and splade.
First I started on a localhost and by running `npm run dev & php artisan serv` everything worked fine.
Now I am trying to upload it to a server but by running `npm run build` I get a blank page.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you